# Lex is not picking up Uber as a slot option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

In AWS Lex have a slot type for car. values are Hire, Taxi. For Taxi, I have defined synonyms like "minicab, taxicab, uber". when I type minicab or taxicab Lex identifies it as Taxi, but when I type uber, it is not recognized it as a synonym for taxi.

This is my synonym options as I have configured: taxis, minicab, taxicab, uber

All synonyms are recognized except uber. Any idea why? Is it a reserved word somewhere?

I am adding the complete json for the slot as requested:
 here is the complete json for the slot:

```
{
  "name": "BankBotCarServiceType", 
  "description": "car service the user is hiring - hire or taxi or chauffeured or rickshaws", 
  "enumerationValues": [
    {"value": "Rickshaws", "synonyms": ["tuk tuk", "scooter", "moped", "auto", "auto rickshaw"]}, 
    {"value": "Chauffeured car", "synonyms": ["chauffeur"]}, 
    {"value": "Hire", "synonyms": ["car hire", "rent", "self drive", "self-drive", "you-drive", "u-drive", "rent a car", "rented vehicle"]}, 
    {"value": "Taxi", "synonyms": ["taxis", "minicab", "taxicab", "Uber", "uber", "uberX"]}
  ], 
  "checksum": "XXXXXXXX", 
  "valueSelectionStrategy": "TOP_RESOLUTION"
}
```

Comment: I don't think uber is a reserved word. Can you please share your code?

Comment: The dialect might be a problem then!

Comment: @JINESHSHAH, what code do you want me to share? It is lex configuration. Do you want the json of the slot? I have added it to the question

Comment: @SharvariNagesh in the Lex console, select Latest for the slot and build it again. It solved similar error in my case.

Comment: @sid8491, No Sid, selecting Latest for slot and building it again doesn't add this particular word. everything else is added

Comment: @SharvariNagesh yes you are right, i have just tried and it is not recognizing Uber. will try to find reason.

Comment: @SharvariNagesh can you check now

Answer (score 2):

I have got in touch with AWS team, and they have confirmed me that **it is a bug of Lex**. This needs a fix from their side and they are actively working on this. I will update this when they roll out the update.

**UPDATE FROM AMAZON TEAM:** Amazon development team have confirmed that they have deployed a fix and it should work fine now.